# Creating super user in MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb

Previously in Mongo 2.6 was possible to create super user that will access all databases. However in the documentation of MongoDB 3.2 I don't see this option. My question is, how can I add a user in MongoDB 3.2 that will have access to all databases?

Comment: Have you try the command in this [page](https://docs.mongodb.org/v2.6/tutorial/add-admin-user/), it does NOT work in version 3.2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [roles are well documented](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/) for MongoDB 3.2

The [superuser roles](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#superuser-roles) *do* provide access to all databases, either directly or implicit. However it is bad practice to do the bread and butter CRUD work with a superuser. You should always apply the [Principle of least privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).

If you only want the user to be able to read all databases, that would be the **[`readAnyDatabase`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readAnyDatabase)** role. If the user should be able to modify all databases, that would translate to the **[`readWriteAnyDatabase`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#readWriteAnyDatabase)** role.

Answer (score -1):

In MongoDB 3.2 you have a bunch of built in roles. You can see them here :
https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/

Unfortunatly there is no "super user" role. You have to give several roles to your user.
Personally my super users have these roles :

- userAdmin or userAdminAnyDatabase : allow him to create users
- clusterAdmin : this role allow me to shutdown databases and manage my cluster
- readWriteAnyDatabase : I think you can guess what it does

But you can add other roles to fit your user to your needs.

Comment: Erm, there are _multiple_ superuser roles, one of them explicit (role **[`root`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#root)**), some implicit (a user with **[`userAdminAnyDatabase`](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/built-in-roles/#userAdminAnyDatabase)** can grant himself any role, including **`root`**).